GoogleCloudStorageConnector Timed Out
I am trying to connect to a database using the GoogleCloudStorageConnector transfomer. I have a json key file which is needed to authenticate the connection, so I set up an environment variable with the path to my json
System Variables
However, when I try to run the transformer to list the files in the bucket, I get this error:
2024-09-02 09:50:24|      |     |WARN  |DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000215AD078B50>, 'Connection to oauth2.googleapis.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)')': /token

When I use gsutil in a command prompt or batch file, it works perfectly fine but FME seems to be struggling.
